# How to restrict use of SFTP feature "escape to local shell"?

Tags: networking, security, users, sftp

In order to make a file server with restricted access, I set the following configuration:

**On the file server (Debian Wheezy)**

- Create a user `data-reader` without home, without shell, in the group named `data`.
- Create a directory `/somewhere/share/` owned by root with a sub-directory `/somewhere/share/data/` accessible by the group `data`.
- Add the following configuration to `/etc/sshd_config`:

  ```
  Match group data
      ChrootDirectory /somewhere/share
      ForcedCommand internal-sftp
      X11Forwarding no
      AllowTcpForwarding no
  ```

That way, `data-reader` can only read files using SFTP in the directory `/somewhere/share/data`. Ok.

**On the client (another Debian)**

Use `sftp data-reader@<server_ip>` to connect to the server.
From the SFTP console I have access in read-only to `/somewhere/share/data` with SFTP commands like `ls` or `get` and I cannot see other paths. Good ! that is what I wanted.

***BUT*** there is this nice command listed with `help`:

```
!    Escape to local shell
```

And if I run

```
!ls /
```

I can actually see all the files from `/` on the server ! I can see the content of any file. But I don’t want that, I want the user not to be able to get out of his directory.

*Is there a way to restrict access of this "escape" command ?*

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escaping to a local shell means just that -- the user now has a shell on the client, *not* on the server.  Touch a file in /tmp on both systems (named differently!) to see the difference.